# What is the need of template lambda introduced in C++20 when C++14 already has generic lambda?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++20, generic-lambda

[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) introduced generic lambdas that made it possible to write following:

```
auto func = [](auto a, auto b){
    return a + b;
};
auto Foo = func(2, 5);
auto Bar = func("hello", "world");
```

It is very clear that this generic lambda `func` works just like a templated function `func` would work.

Why did the C++ committee decide to add template syntax for generic lamda?

Comment: What if you need to use a *different* template type than for the arguments or return type? And what if it's needed inside the body?

Comment: I've been told [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745972) was an interesting use case.

Comment: See this for a comparison of the different lambda versions: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/more-powerful-lambdas-with-c-20

Answer (score 134, accepted):

C++14 generic lambdas are a very cool way to generate a functor with an `operator ()` that looks like this:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto operator()(T t, U u) const;
```

But not like this:

```
template <class T>
auto operator()(T t1, T t2) const; // Same type please
```

Nor like this:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
auto operator()(std::array<T, N> const &) const; // Only `std::array` please
```

Nor like this (although this gets a bit tricky to actually use):

```
template <class T>
auto operator()() const; // No deduction
```

C++14 lambdas are fine, but C++20 allows us to implement these cases without hassle.

Comment: Nice and concise. Just adding this: The first (same types) can be solved by `(auto a, decltype(a) b)` in C++14.

Comment: @SebastianMach almost. With that solution `b` is non-deduced, and its argument will be implicitly converted to the type of `a` instead.

Answer (score 44):

Since you can use templated lambdas in C++20, you can restrict your types in an easier way than an SFINAE expression:

```
auto lambda = []<typename T>(std::vector<T> t){};
```

This lambda will work only with vector types.

Comment: How is `consteval` related to the new syntax? It's cool and all, but I don't get the relevance.

Comment: It is more an information about what C++20 add to the lambda expression than an answer to the question

Answer (score 30):

> The new "familiar template syntax" for lambdas introduced in C++20
> makes constructs such as `for_types` and `for_range` viable and way more
> readable compared to C++17 alternatives.

(source: [compile-time iteration with C++20 lambdas](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/cpp20_lambdas_compiletime_for.html))

Another interesting thing that can be done on both C++14 and C++17 generic lambdas is directly calling `operator()` by explicitly passing a template parameter:
**C++14**:

```cpp
auto l = [](auto){ };
l.template operator()<int>(0);
```

**C++20** (see also the explanation for `<tparams>` [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)):

```cpp
auto l = []<typename T>(){ };
l.template operator()<int>();
```

The C++14 example above is quite useless: there's no way of referring to the type provided to `operator()` in the body of the lambda without giving the argument a name and using `decltype`. Additionally, we're forced to pass an argument even though we might not need it.

The C++20 example shows how T is easily accessible in the body of the lambda and that a nullary lambda can now be arbitrarily templated. This is going to be very useful for the implementation of the aforementioned compile-time constructs.

Answer (score 27):

The [proposal](https://wg21.link/p0428) that was accepted into C++20 has a lengthy motivation section, with examples. The premise of it is this:

> There are a few key reasons why the current syntax for defining
>   generic lambdas is deemed insufficient by the author. The gist of it is
>   that some things that can be done easily with normal function templates
>   require significant hoop jumping to be done with generic lambdas, or
>   can’t be done at all.The author thinks that lambdas are valuable
>   enough that C++ should support them just as well as normal function
>   templates.

Following that are quite a few examples.