# Can I static assert that an entity is instantiation of a template class without enforcing any/all template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, static-assert

Maybe the question in the title is too generic, and it is generic because I'm curious about

But this generic question sprung from a concrete, less generic use case.

I initially wrote a function dealing with an array of 2 elements of class `A`:

```cpp
auto /* return type is not relevant */ fun(std::array<A,2>& a) {
    // ... do things...
}
```

then I decided to extend the functionality to the case that `a` has 3 elements. Handling this by using a `std::vector<A>` is not an option as the two scenarios never interact with each other and I never need to `push_back` on/`pop_back` from `a`.

To make the two of them work together, I gave up on the explicit parameter type and relied on `auto`:

```cpp
auto /* ditto */ fun(auto& a) {
    // ... do things, which depend on `auto` having deduced a `std::array<A,N>` for some `N`...
}
```

Doing so however is a bit undesirable because:

- the code is less self-documenting than it could be: someone else (or myself in a month) would have to go look inside `fun` in order to undestand that it uses `a` assuming that it is a `std::array<A,N>` for a general `N`;
- the error messages are less clear than they could be: the error would be along the lines of *no function matches this call*, whereas I'd like the error to be *this function works with `std::array` of `A`s*.

What I could do, is keep `auto` and `static_assert`ing in the first line of the function that `a` be `std::array<A,2>` or `std::array<A,3>`, but in the future I might want to handle the case `4` too.

So I'm just wandering if there's a way to assert that a variable `a` is instance of a given template class, e.g. `std::array`, with *not all* template parameters specified.

In general, given a tempalte class like this,

```cpp
template<typename A, int n, typename B, int m>
class C { /* impl */ };
```

is it possible to assert that a variable `a` is of type `C<some_class,some_number,?,?>`?

Comment: It seems like your question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605) one. Or at least related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your function a template. N will be deduced automatically.

```
template<std::size_t N>
auto fun(std::array<A,N>& a) {
   // ... do things, which depend on `auto` having deduced a `std::array<A,N>` for some `N`...
}
```

Comment: Does this work if `fun` is not a function but a lambda? Sorry, but in an attempt to simplify the question I forgot to specify _in my case `fun` is actually a lamda_.

Comment: @Enrico everything you can do with lambdas, you can also do without lambdas, so maybe you can consider that.

Comment: @Enrico Then, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126204/580083.

Comment: @DanielLangr, I'm accepting user253751's answer because it does answer my (kind of flawed) question. However, than you for linking that, which very very very useful to know.

Comment: @Enrico - Starting from C++20 you can use template lambdas and write something `[]<std::size_t N>(std::array<A, N> & a){ /* .... */ }`